# How to query for a certain Day (DateField) in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have an app in which I need to query the database for a certain date, to check if there is an entry already for date x for user y.

I have a model that has the following field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    day = models.DateField()
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In the forms.py I have:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

and in the views.py code I want to check if this day exists in the database, so I run:

```
from datetime import date
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.forms import MyForm
...
#inside the view function
form = MyForm(request.POST)
day = date(form.day)
if days.objects.filter(user=request.user, day=bookday).exists():
... do stuff
```

And it gives me:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_url/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'myapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/django/env/myproject/myapp/views.py" in test_url
  26.             bookday = date(form.day)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /test_url/
Exception Value: 'MyForm' object has no attribute 'day'
```

Although it clearly does have the day form as a DateField. How can I do what is needed in this case?

The POST data:

```
POST
Variable    Value

csrfmiddlewaretoken =    u'blahblah'

day =   u'03/27/2013'

user =  u'2'
```

The HTML template form:

```
<form method="post" action="." >
{{ form.user }}
{{ form.day}}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

EDIT: I clarified the code and put the stacktrace.

Comment: which line raises the error? can you include the traceback and the definition of your model class?

Comment: where does `days` come from? Please post the entire views function you are working on. You are missing critical information. `bookday` is a datetime object and `MyForm` looks like a regular form. Not a DB model.

Comment: @shx2 I included the traceback and model definition

Comment: @CppLearner I added the missing details. Stacktrace, DB model, Form, HTML template, and the POSTed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work. The fix was so simple. In the line where I need to get the POSTed day value, I just use:

```
day = form.cleaned_data['day']
```

Instead of what I previously had:

```
day = date(form.day) #WRONG CODE
```

and then pass that to the database as a normal days.objects.filter(user=request.user, day=day) line.